# How to find out the slope of the linear regression line fitted by ggplot's stat_smooth()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made a plot using ggplot with the following code:

```
ggplot(tb_us, aes(year_new, count)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

The plot is below:
[image]

This is all good. But I am also interested in finding out the slope of this linearly fitted line. How can I do that? Thanks